# jQuery disable event listener until event finished

Tags: jquery

I have four tabs, one of them is active by default. When a non-active tab is clicked, it expands and the active one shrinks.

The problem I have is when a non-active tab is clicked during an animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/wFHBR/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').bind('click',function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('activetab')){
            $('.activetab').removeClass('activetab',500);
            $(this).addClass('activetab',500);
        }
    });
});
```

I know animation stacking questions are asked all the time but I cant find a solution to this particular example.

I don't want an animation to be stopped, reversed or queued. I just want any clicks on any other tab to be completely ignored IF an animation is still going.

Many thanks!

Comment: why don't u avoid this entirely by just creating classes that have CSS animation instead of animating the classes by jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a global variable to indicate whether you are in animation state right now. Set it to `true` in the beginning of `click` handler, back to `false` in one of animation methods callback. And check it to decide if you should go inside `click` handler or not. I edited you fiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/vSWdS/

```
 var currently = false;
$('.tab').bind('click',function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('activetab') && !currently){
        currently = true;
        $('.activetab').removeClass('activetab',500);
        $(this).addClass('activetab',500, "swing", function(){
            currently = false;
        });
    }
});
```